# I want to create a Bing translator, but the appid I got is invalid

Tags: c#, microsoft-translator, bing-translator-api

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace Translator
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void btnTranslate_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
                string strTranslatedText = null;
                try
                {
                    TranslatorService.LanguageServiceClient client = new TranslatorService.LanguageServiceClient();
                    client = new TranslatorService.LanguageServiceClient();
                    strTranslatedText = client.Translate("b86b637103504cd4bdd4e1388a56e039", txtTraslatedFrom.Text, "", "en");
                    txtTranslatedText.Text = strTranslatedText;
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
                }
        }
    }
}


<configuration>
    <startup> 
        <supportedRuntime version="v4.0" sku=".NETFramework,Version=v4.6.1" />
    </startup>
    <system.serviceModel>
        <bindings>
            <basicHttpBinding>
                <binding name="BasicHttpBinding_LanguageService" />
                <binding name="BasicHttpBinding_LanguageService1" />
                <binding name="BasicHttpBinding_LanguageService2" />
            </basicHttpBinding>
        </bindings>
        <client>
             <endpoint name="BasicHttpBinding_LanguageService" 
                 address="http://api.microsofttranslator.com/V1/soap.svc"
                 binding="basicHttpBinding" 
                 bindingConfiguration="BasicHttpBinding_LanguageService"
                 contract="TranslatorService.LanguageService" />
        </client>
    </system.serviceModel>
</configuration>
```

http://www.dotnetcurry.com/ShowArticle.aspx?ID=357

The above is a link to create a Bing translator, I followed the exact same steps but my app never works. I have no idea why it says my AppID is invalid, I spent an hour to get this id. Do you guys know how and where I can get a correct ID for this app?

Comment: Try googling "how do i get a bing app id"

Comment: I tried it. I followed the exact instruction how to get the bing app id. I subscribed the free plan for the bing text translator, and now I am able to get two app id. however, these won't work on my code which is invalid.

Answer (score 0):

The (free) App ID mechanism has been deprecated several years ago.

To access the Microsoft Translator API (be it text or speech) you need to get an Azure subscription and use the key provided there. There is a free tier at 2M characters a month. If you need more than this it starts at a $10 per M characters.

To get started: https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/translator/getstarted.aspx

Comment: Hi, thanks for your advice. That is what I did to get my App ID, but the code is not working when I copy my App ID in it. The error is Invalid APP ID. I don't know if it is something wrong with my code